# maven unit test fails but passes independently

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to transition one of my java projects into a `maven` build.  I'm having trouble with the testing portion and looking for pointers.  This is my first maven project, so it is totally possible I'm missing something basic...

I have a set of tests similar to below that pass when run inside of my IDE (IntelliJ) but when I clean and run the maven tests, I get weird fails in the `surefire-reports`.  It appears that the `@BeforeEach` portion of the test is not run under the maven structure, which would explain the "null" accusations below, but I'm not sure.  I'm running Java 16 and my `pom.xml` is included below along with the simple example, and failure report.

On the issue of the pom.xml...  I'm kind of stabbing in the dark for the dependencies here for `junit` and others.  Is there a better/canonical way to build the dependencies in the pom.xml for the imports used in the code?  Perhaps there is something in IntelliJ that I have not discovered yet, but I seem to web surf for each dependency.

##### test code

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.HashSet;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestKiller {
    private HashSet<Integer> mySet;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
        mySet = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd(){
        mySet.add(1);
        assertEquals(mySet.size(), 1, "should have 1 element");
    }
}
```

##### maven's surefire-report *"claim"* of failure...

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: schedule.TestKiller
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec <<< FAILURE!
schedule.TestKiller.testAdd()  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.HashSet.add(Object)" because "this.mySet" is null
    at schedule.TestKiller.testAdd(TestKiller.java:24)
```

##### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>AirSked</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>MakeSimpleSked.java</excludes>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>


</project>
```

Comment: ..I assume in your case: a (too) old `maven-surefire-plugin` is to blame. Please try: set to the latest version. What is your maven version?

Comment: @xerx593  Thank you.  I didn't have a `maven-surefire-plugin` specified, so who knows what was running.  I guess I kinda suspected some config w/ surefire as well, but I'm not familiar with it -- and didn't know it needed a plugin to work.  Seems odd.  Anyhow, after adding the latest plugin (version 2.22.2) we are a go!  Thanks

Comment: Unless you overwrite/set it, the "default plugins" (all of `org.apache.maven.plugins`) depend on the used maven version ;(glad, it could help!:)

Comment: `mvn help:effective-pom` (or according view in IDE) can (little) unmystify maven